# How to find the database a Django record was loaded from?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

How do you find the database that a record was loaded from, utilizing Django's [multiple database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/) support?

I know how to retrieve a record from the non-default database by doing:

```
record = MyModel.objects.using('otherdatabase').get(id=123)
```

But given the record, how do I lookup the `using` value? I tried:

```
record._default_manager.db
```

but this always returns `default`, regardless of the value I sent to `using()`.

Comment: What does `record.model` give you?

Comment: @MattCremeens, AttributeError: object has no attribute 'model'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_state` seems to hold what you're looking for.

```
record._state.db
```

If you're interested, it's used internally in the source code here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/db/models/base/